# How can I obtain instructions distribution from an executable binary file

Tags: linux, statistics, binaryfiles

This may sound a little insane, but I want to know the instructions distribution of an executable binary file. Say I have an executable compiled for ARM 32bit. I want to get something like:

```
mov: xxx times
blx: xxx times
vadd: xxx times
```

Anybody know a tool that can do this? Thanks